# Wordpress plugin reporting IPs bypassing htaccess deny rule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security

Wordpress plugin Sucuri Security has been notifying that random IPs are trying to login to my site. My .htaccess is setup to deny all IPs that are not ours:

```
<Files wp-login.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from OUR.SPECIFIC.IP.ONLY
</Files>
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Are the IPs able to bypass the rule? How, and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure, you can also block access to the /wp-admin folder with this code in an .htaccess file located **inside** /wp-admin. The code is from here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks#Limit_Access_to_wp-admin_by_IP

```
# Block access to wp-admin.
order deny,allow
allow from x.x.x.x 
deny from all

# Allow access to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
<Files admin-ajax.php>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Satisfy any
</Files>
```

For more information about what the notifications mean, contact the developers of the plugin.